# Rake task to find attributes with nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I'm building a Rake Task to collect records that have a nil value for featured

```
namespace :updates do
  desc "Update from nil values"
  task :companies => :environment do
    nil_featured_companies = Company.where("featured = ?", nil)
    nil_featured_companies.each do |co|
      co.update_featured_to_false
    end
...
```

When I check it in rails console, I get nothing back. If I modify the query to search for false values, I get a collection back

```
Company.where("featured = ?", false)
```

I want to get only the records with featured values of nil and update them to false. What's the correct syntax to find all featured values with nil?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Company.where(featured: nil)
```

or

```
Company.where("featured is null")
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get an <Company::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fed48602230> and when I run companies.each {|c| c.update_attribute(:featured, false)} I get this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."featured" IS NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Company.where(featured: nil).each do |co|
   co.update_attribute(:featured, false)
end
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction is aborted

Means that PG raised an exceptions and future transactions are not allowed in this connection

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you're sure the data type is a boolean, right?)

```
  Company.where(featured: nil).each do |each|
    each.update_attribute("featured", false)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
Company.where("featured is ?", nil)
```